# Lookup with different variants

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for VLookup. Problem is that I want to have several variants for country name so it should use them all before it will give an error. So it should look in Column A, then Column B, then Column C.

My data (Sheet "Countries"):

[image]

My code:

```
Sub PasteFormulaToRange()

    Dim refRng As Range, ref As Range, dataRng As Range

    Set refRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("K2:K969") 'horizontal range of look up values
    Set dataRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Countries").Range("A2:D198") 'data block you want to look up value in

    For Each ref In refRng
        ref.Offset(0, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ref, dataRng, 4, False)
    Next ref
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to build your own searching mechanism, vlookup will only work for the leftmost column in a range. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLookup is not capable of searching multiple columns, what you want to do is use `Range.Find` to locate the row, then pull the data in column 4.  There are more arguments for `Range.Find` that you can reference here https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/

```
Sub NewPasteFormulatoRange()

    Dim refRng As Range, ref As Range, dataRng As Range
    Dim foundrow as Long
    Set refRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("K2:K969") 'horizontal range of look up values
    Set dataRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Countries").Range("A2:C198") 'data block you want to look up value in

    For Each ref In refRng
        Set findref = dataRng.Find(ref)
        If Not findref Is Nothing Then
            foundrow = findref.Row
            ref.Offset(0, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Countries").Cells(foundrow, 4)
        End If
    Next ref
End Sub
```

Comment: Edited to check if result is found